# Error: Compile Error: Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement

Tags: apex, upload

I am trying to upload a data file to salesforce on my custom object. This is similar to gmail upload. Here i have attached the code regarding this but  i am getting error.
I am getting this error.

Error:

> Compile Error: Non-void method might not return a value or might have
>   statement after a return statement. at line 82 column 1

code:

```
public class FileUploadController { 
private String fileName; 
private Integer fileSize; 
private Blob fileBody; 
public FileUploadController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
} 
public FileUploadController(){
}
public String getFileName() { 
    return this.fileName; 
}
public void setFileName(String fileName) { 
    this.fileName = fileName; 
}
public Blob getFileBody() { 
    return this.fileBody; 
}
public void setFileBody(Blob fileBody) { 
    this.fileBody = fileBody; 
    setFileSize(this.fileBody.size()); 
} 
public Integer getFileSize() { 
    return this.fileSize; 
} 
public void setFileSize(Integer fileSize) { 
    this.fileSize = fileSize; 
} 
private Database.SaveResult insertUpload() { 
    Upload_c uploadObj = new Upload_c(); // fill out cust obj fields return     Database.insert(uploadObj); 
} 
private Database.SaveResult insertAttachment(Id parentId) { 
    Database.SaveResult result;
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(); 
    attachment.Body = this.fileBody; 
    attachment.Name = this.fileName; 
    attachment.ParentId = parentId;
    result = Database.insert(attachment); 
    fileBody = Blob.valueOf(' '); 
    return result; 
} 
public PageReference processUpload() { 
    try { 
        Database.SaveResult result = insertUpload();
        if (result == null || !result.isSuccess()) { 
            return null; 
        }
        result = insertAttachment(result.getId()); 
        if (result == null || !result.isSuccess()) { 
            return null; 
        } 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { 
        ApexPages.AddMessages(e); 
    } //return Url(); 
} 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create a Vf page to upload a data file](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10607/how-to-create-a-vf-page-to-upload-a-data-file)

Comment: The error clearly states the problem, and indicates you have a lack of understanding of programming concepts in general. Have you tried finding or looking up what the exact problem is yourself ? Any search engine will likely give you good results.

Answer (score 3):

I see one method, that returns nothing if an error occurs `processUpload()`. Try to add `return null` just to the end of the method:

```
public PageReference processUpload() { 
    try { 
        ....
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { 
        ....
    }
    return null;
}
```